# What should be in a model

Tags: mvvm

I am struggling with the question of what belongs in the Model in a MVVM architecture.  Suppose I have an object called a Line which is made up of x,y data point pairs.  I want to be able to add points to the line and I want to be able to do interpolation of points.  For instance, I want to return a vector of y values when the user passes in a vector of x values.  In order to do the interpolation I need the points in the Line object to be sorted in ascending x.  Should the model just be the collection of Points?  Does the model handle the sorting and interpolation or should a service handle this?

Comment: Usually raw data is located in the domain-model and the representation data, i.e. functions, sorting, manipulation are situated in the 'clientside'-view-model

Answer (score 0):

> What should be in a model?

Short answer: The data

Longer answer:

The model represents the part of the application that is dedicated to data storage. So database access goes in the model. A good represention of that is a Repository-Pattern. (Which, in a more rigid interpretation of MVVM belongs to the service layer).

Your ViewModel holds the dynamic data. This means selection, ordering, locales, and so on.

A very good start on MVVM (and MVVM in action) is this [video by Jason Dolinger](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650). The sourcecode of the example [can be found here](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2689)

It is just one hour long, but i covers very good the aspects of MVVM and why it is that successful.

Comment: Say I have the following: Line, LineViewModel, LineView. Does the Line object only have a collection of Points.  Then the LineViewModel is responsible for adding Points and sorting the points?  Should the LineViewModel be responsible for doing interpolation (LineViewModel.Interpolate(double[] Points))?

Comment: Exactly, the Line is a collection of points. The LineViewModel will add coordinates to the line as given from the UI. Interpolation should be done in a library I believe, but that can be called from the ViewModel of course.